# How can I close the extra window on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

It's super annoying, every time I open a file it opens like that:
[image]

On the right window, so I need to drag it to the middle every time. I can't figure out how to close this window.

Comment: This is not the built-in dark theme, but it looks like you have installed the _Dev Style_ or _Darkest Dark_ theme. This installed plugin you tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. In Eclipse, you can reset the perspective via the menu _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective_.

Comment: @howlger Thanks.